# An Example of complicated define in C

Tags: c

```
#define _FUID1(x) __attribute__((section("__FUID1.sec"),space(prog))) int _FUID1 = (x);
```

I am trying to make sense of the about the above define.  the _FUID(x) macro. This relates to program memory and has the attribute of the section defining in the code section memory area?
what does the above trying to accomplish?

Comment: well, just terminology, but defines are always simple, as dump preprocessors can understand and use them.. I guess you're asking what `__attribute__((section("__FUID1.sec"),space(prog))) int _FUID1 = (x);` is.

Comment: The problem with that is that most of it is compiler specific, and probably GCC specific at that.  It is creating a variable `_FUID1` (which is a bad name to use; it is reserved for the implementation to use such names) of type `int` with initial value `x` provided as a parameter, and with esoteric specification of where the variable is to be stored in the program (in a section `__FUID1.sec`). I'm not sure what the `space(prog)` means.

Answer (score 4):

The macro isn't doing anything interesting or complicated at all; it just outputs a declaration for `int _FUID1`, with its parameter as an initializer, and with an attributes list ahead of it.

As for what the attributes list means, look at [the documentation for variable attributes in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html). `section` puts the variable in a named section, which allows the linker to relocate it to a special address or do some other interesting thing to it, and `space` isn't documented, but `space(prog)` sounds like a directive to put a value into the program address space instead of the data address space on a Harvard-architecture machine.

Comment: I'd not seen `space(prog)` either, but if it is 'in the program address space', doesn't that mean it will be a read-only (constant) value?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, as far as I know.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler (a chip with a read-write separate program space isn't impossible, but I don't know one :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is hardware specific (some Microchip unit), it places a value, for example:

```
 __attribute__((section("__FUID1.sec"),space(prog))) int _FUID1 = (0xf1);
```

into unit id register 1 (`__FUID1.sec`), in the program flash to configure the hardware. See the [pic documentation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70194C.pdf) (for references to FUID) and [MPLAB C30 manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51284c.pdf) (for description of memory spaces).